# Problems with SQL EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, exists

I'm going mad on this one. I have the following SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [BankImport].[spBI_getIsBatchUnique]
    @batchName varchar = 500
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [ACN_Main].[BankImport].[tblBI_Jobs]
            WHERE [batchNumber] = @batchName))
        BEGIN
            SELECT 1
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT 0
        END     
    END
GO
```

But whatever the request is, I always get back 0!

I tried to modify it in several ways but with no success!
What I need to do is check if there is a record with that batch number and return true, otherwise return false.

Any tip?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your input parameter looks a bit funny

```
@batchName varchar = 500
```

Should it have been this?

```
@batchName varchar(500)
```

Ie set the length of the varchar datatype, how you currently have it, 500 is the default value for the `batchName` param.

Comment: +1 At the moment it gives a `varchar(1)` a default value of `500` which is automatically truncated to `*`. That can't be the desired effect!

Comment: You where right!!!! What a miss!!! I lost two hours on it, rewrote 10 times in different way the query!

Thanks!

Comment: @MaiOM Always define char/varchar/nchar/nvarchar with length. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think because you compare batchNumber and batchName, try

```
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [ACN_Main].[BankImport].[tblBI_Jobs]
        WHERE [batchName] = @batchName)
```

Comment: That is just a naming miss match. I solved it, check @mouters answer. Thanks anyway